# Unable to extract mysql json data while using where clause

Tags: java, mysql, sqldatatypes, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have a table with the below json data type column in a table TABLESDATA

**create table tablesdata(sample json);**

And I am using the sql to query the table.

```
select sample->>"$[*].name" as new_data from tablesdata WHERE sample ->>'$[*].name' = "EDFG";
```

The sample json data is like below

```
[
    {
        "name": "EDFG",
        "isUsed": true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Article_color_lookup_id",
                "isUsed": false,
                "dataType": "INTEGER"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "ABCDE",
        "isUsed": false,
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Article_lookup_criteria_id",
                "isUsed": false,
                "dataType": "INTEGER"
            },
        ]
    },
.............so on
]
```

But the query is not returning any rows. What am I doing wrong here?

I need the output will be like

```
[
    {
        "name": "EDFG",
    },
    {
        "name": "EDFG",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using JSON search functions instead of where clause
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Like following some example

Search all items with the 'JavaScript' tag

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, '["JavaScript"]');
```

Find all items with tags starting 'Java':

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', 'Java%') IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of sample->>"$[*].name" is like an array so the result of where condition will be false
["EDFG", "ABCDE"] != "EDFG"

in your example it would be like

```json
["EDFG", "ABCDE"]
```

Now you can search in array using json_search

```sql
select sample->"$[*].name" as new_data from tablesdata where JSON_SEARCH(sample, 'all', 'EDFG') is not null
```

---

**Update**

If you need to search for exactly matches you may search like this

```sql
select sample->>"$[*].name" as new_data from tablesdata WHERE sample ->>'$[*].name' = '["EDFG"]';
```

Comment: I have tried with your query but getting results as ["EDFG", "ABCDE"] but i need only the match values Ex : ["EDFG"]

Comment: I just updated my post. you can look for an array instead of an array member. sample ->>'$[*].name' = '["EDFG"]';

Comment: I have tried with the update query also. But the query is not returning any rows.

Comment: To be more clear run the query without any where condition and highlight those rows that you are looking for.

Comment: updated the post